# Open Unidentified .pkg file

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

So I wanted to download the git command line and when opening the .pkg I got an Un ID'd Developer message.

I do not have admin rights and am locked out of the gatekeeper panel.

I then tried the `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`  method to no avail.

Any tips?

Thanks!

NOTE: OSX El Capitan

Comment: Blocked by design! You'll need an admin password. Like, absolutely need an admin password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new folder, put the PKG you want to install into this new folder, CD to that directory then run these commands:

`xar -x -f Install.pkg && rm Install.pkg && xar -cf Install.pkg * && open Install.pkg`

(replace Install.pkg with the file name of the PKG file you want to install.)

These commands decompress the PKG, delete the original PKG, then create a new PKG, which should install without complaining about unidentified developers.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do I create a new pkg? I got 3 files named "Bom", "PackageInfo" and "Payload" Is there a command or programI must use? Thanks again

Comment: The new PKG file replaces "Install.pkg", which should open itself after you run these commands. The "Bom", "PackageInfo" and "Payload" files were extracted from the old PKG. The old PKG is then deleted, and a new PKG is created in its place.